# Fragment getArguments() return null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-fragments

Fragment `getArguments()` return null pointer exception.
Already a consecutive day thinks how to fix this code, the entire Internet has climbed in search of an answer. Please help me. Code like the faithful, but for some reason crashes NullPointerException?

P.S. Sorry for my English, but I think you understand what I'm trying to ask.))

//Fragment

```
public static AppsManagerFragment userFragList(int a){
    AppsManagerFragment f = new AppsManagerFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("secretKey", a);
    f.setArguments(bundle);
    return f;

};

public static AppsManagerFragment systemFragList(int a){
    AppsManagerFragment f = new AppsManagerFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("secretKey", a);
    f.setArguments(bundle);
    return f;

};


int getFragmentArg() {
    return this.getArguments().getInt("secretKey"); // here there NPE
}
```

//Activity

```
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
private DataApps dApps;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.apps_manager_activity);
    dApps = new DataApps(this);

  // instance initialization
  AppsManagerFragment userFrag = AppsManagerFragment.userFragList(1);
  AppsManagerFragment systemFrag = AppsManagerFragment.systemFragList(2);

  mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
  mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"), userFrag.getClass(), null);
  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2"), systemFrag.getClass(), null);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Fragment getArguments() return null pointer exception:

From your code, I can able to understand that you are returning a static instance of the fragment, but in `getFragmentArg()` method you are accessing a non static instance of the fragment. Actually you should follow `findFragmentByTag()` method and then use the `getArguments()` on that instance. It will solve your issue.